# How to get browser current page url or page view source in Sabre red workspace plugin

Tags: sabre

I am new to Sabre red app development. My redapp use case is to open remote website into browser editor and get the current page url or some view source code.

I am able to open website into browser. However, I am not able to get the url of current page.
I am using `FocusOrOpenWebkitEditorHandler (com.sabre.edge.platform.optional.webkit.handlers.FocusOrOpenWebkitEditorHandler)` to open the website.

Answer (score 0):

The Browser Editor (aka WebKit) implementation on RedApp SDK, actually abstracts the browser engine (swt/javax component) from the developer, unfortunately there's NO public APIs or methods exposed to do something like getHTML().
The RedApp SDK offer way to open such Browser Editors "programatically", set URL, and to execute javascript code after page loads, also u can configure a java -> javascript bridge that will inject javascript code on loaded page that allow u to pass some values from javascript to java. If u can refine your use case, please notice that there's no "address bar" on browser editor, so U as developer are in control on which url to load, but cannot "hook" to any url change event.